# Customizing Latex preamble in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I want to use the Latex \Box command in matplotlib, basically in this way:

```
r'$\frac{\Omega}{\Box}$'
```

However the symbol seems not to exist in the standard Latex package (something like \boxdot apperently does and this is working just fine).
I found an apperent solution here that adds the according package to the Latex preamble:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amssymb}']
```

However, this give me this error without even using the \Box command:

```
RuntimeError: dvipng was not able to process the following string:
b''

Here is the full report generated by dvipng:
C:\Users\localUser\.matplotlib\tex.cache\d15b47f0f8595e42b2c46701ea7f7958.dvi: No such 
file or directory
This is dvipng 1.15 Copyright 2002-2015 Jan-Ake Larsson
```

Any Ideas where the problem is or a different solution to use \Box?

I am using Python with Spyder
    '3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]'

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you sure you have `amssymb` installed as package in your latex installation?

Comment: yes,it is installed.